# How to read value of a field updated by ng-model in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

**HTML file**

```
<input id="myName" ng-model="myName" val="{{myName}}">
```

**Coffee Script file**

```
$http.get('/api/name').then(
    (resp) ->
      $scope.myName = resp.data.name
      $('#myName').val() # this is still ""    
    ,
    (errorResp) ->
      # code
  )
```

As you can see from the code above  I'm trying to get the value from my API and then adding it to the scope. I have an event binding in jQuery that every time the input value changes, it draws the name to a canvas. Thing is, when I bind resp.data.name to $scope.myName the .val() still returns "" as if the input haven't changed.

Comment: why need `$('#myName').val()` ? you can check by `$scope.myName`

Comment: @shaishabroy because i have another script with an event listener and would like to reuse it

Answer (score 1):

The value of input will be updated at the end of the current digest cycle. You can wait for it with a [`$timeout`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) (inject it to your controller):

```
(resp) ->
  $scope.myName = resp.data.name
  $timeout ->
    $('#myName').val()
```

and HTML:

```
<input id="myName" ng-model="myName">
```

However, I strongly recommend you to read [“Thinking in AngularJS” if I have a jQuery background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background) and [How does data binding work in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682092/how-does-data-binding-work-in-angularjs?rq=1).

Answer (score 0):

No need to use `val="{{myName}}"` in input element just use `ng-model="myName"` so no need use JQuery to set or get value. you can try using `$timeout` in your response if get data from response but input hasn't changed.

```
<input type="text" id="myName" ng-model="myName">
```

Coffee Script file

```
$http.get('/api/name').then(
    (resp) ->
      $scope.myName = resp.data.name    
    ,
    (errorResp) ->
      # code
  )
```